# KML - Dynamic Screen Overlay Icon

Tags: kml, google-earth

I'm looking to add a dynamic google chart URL as a screen overlay with KML. The chart image is generated by the parameters in the URL, but since the output is not an image file, I am getting an error.
I have had success adding charts to descriptions within balloons, but I cannot seem to use CDATA tags within icon style tags. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<ScreenOverlay>
    <name>Chart</name>
    <Icon>
        <href>http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World</href>
    </Icon>
    <overlayXY x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <screenXY x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <rotationXY x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <size x="0" y="0" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
</ScreenOverlay>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Must escape the URL in [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) block or use [XML entity/character references](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/01/31/qanda.html).

```
<Icon>
    <href>
      <![CDATA[http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World]]>
    </href>
</Icon>
```

Encode special characters with XML entity references (e.g., '&' => `&amp;`)
or character references ('|' => `&#x7C;`)

```
<Icon>
    <href>http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&amp;chd=t:60,40&amp;chs=250x100&amp;chl=Hello&#x7C;World</href>
</Icon>
```

Comment: Why *HTML* entities? Surely you mean XML entities? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

Comment: Thanks barry, XML has a subset of the HTML entities. These terms are often used interchangeably.